# Is it possible to extract frames from corrupted mp4?

Tags: mp4

I have an mp4 file that I'm trying to recover. The file is missing a moov atom. I've tried all the usual utilities like ffmpeg, remoover, untrunc but all of them failed. I'm wondering now if it is at all possible to just extract a few frames from the video. It is timestamped security footage so any frames I could pull could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try TMPG Smart Renderer https://tmpgenc.pegasys-inc.com/en/product/tmsr5.html

If anything is recoverable, this tool should work. If it can't pull anything from the file, I don't know of any other tool that would. The trial version should work fine for you to get what you need.